# Mouse movement telemetry

Tags: linux, x11, mouse

How can I log how far the mouse travels over time, in order to later produce a graph over mouse movement over time?

The goal is to be able to create a utility for monitoring mouse movement.

Comment: It is definitely possible.  There is quite a lot of "mouse odometer/speedometer" software.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a piece of software? I can't find any for Linux (found Xodo, that does not seem to be available anymore). I've searched on Github, Google and Arch Linux AUR.

Answer (score 1):

There are many X11 tools using the XTest or other extensions that can get mouse movements, such as **cnee**, but you can also just read `/dev/input/mice` on most systems, and get a stream of 3 bytes as you would from an old PS/2 mouse. This bit of python will decode the x,y values and calculate the pixel distance you move. Note, the default permissions of the dev file do not allow reading to other than group `input`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# calc mouse distance travelled
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/397985/119298
import struct
total = 0.
with open("/dev/input/mice") as fd:
    while True:
        x, y = struct.unpack("xbb", fd.read(3))
        total += (x*x+y*y)**.5
        print("%d" % total)
```

Comment: Thanks! Created a small project for logging to CSV + console graph, if you should be interested: https://github.com/xyproto/mouselog